# How can I show thumbnails of files and folders in my app?

Tags: uwp

I'm building an app where I want to show thumbnails of files and folders from disc. How can I do that?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please review how to ask good questions on stackoverflow http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have access to a folder (through user selection with a `FolderPicker` or through the capabilities like `Pictures Library`) you can retrieve the thumbnails from the system. You can use the `GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync()` for that. For instance:

```
private async Task<BitmapImage> GetThumbnail(StorageFile file)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        StorageItemThumbnail thumb = await file.GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.VideosView);
        if (thumb != null)
        {
            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
            await img.SetSourceAsync(thumb);
            return img;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```